# All the Bower component icons not displaying

Tags: civicrm.settings, civicrm-event

Not sure whether this happened post WP update (to WP 5.2) but now none of the icons under bower_components/jquery_ui/.../images. No paths were changed/updated in System settings.  Tooltips still show, but all the little icons/images are broken, any idea why or how to debug?  The .png files are definitely there, no access permissions changed.